# Should I change background of a ListView row in custom adapter or in activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a `ListView` which I populate using a custom adapter. I want to check for an entry within a `ListView` layout and if it matches then change the entire row's background color to something different.

Is it recommended to change within the custom adapter itself or in Main activity?

I am currently changing the background color in the custom adapter and for some reason multiple row's background color is changing and also if I scroll up and down the `ListView` rows that the background color changed switches to other rows.

I can post code to my custom adapter if need be.

My CustomAdapter class:

```
package com.test.testing;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SetRowsCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SetRows> {
    Context context;
   int layoutResourceId;
   ArrayList<SetRows> data=new ArrayList<SetRows>();
   DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEE, LLLL d", Locale.US);
   String[] suspendedDates = {
            "Tuesday, January 1",
            "Monday, January 20",
            "Friday, January 31",
            "Wednesday, February 12",
            "Monday, February 17",
            "Wednesday, March 5",
            "Sunday, March 16",
            "Tuesday, April 15",
            "Wednesday, April 16",
            "Thursday, April 17",
            "Friday, April 18",
            "Monday, April 21",
            "Tuesday, April 22",
            "Monday, May 26",
            "Thursday, May 29",
            "Wednesday, June 4",
            "Thursday, June 5",
            "Friday, July 4",
            "Monday, July 28",
            "Tuesday, July 29",
            "Wednesday, July 30",
            "Friday, August 15",
            "Monday, September 1",
            "Thursday, September 25",
            "Friday, September 26",
            "Saturday, October 4",
            "Sunday, October 5",
            "Monday, October 6",
            "Thursday, October 9",
            "Friday, October 10",
            "Monday, October 13",
            "Thursday, October 16",
            "Friday, October 17",
            "Thursday, October 23",
            "Saturday, November 1",
            "Tuesday, November 4",
            "Tuesday, November 11",
            "Thursday, November 27",
            "Monday, December 8",
            "Thursday, December 25"
    };
   public SetRowsCustomAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<SetRows> data) {
       super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
       this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
       this.context = context;
       this.data = data;
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       View row = convertView;
       ImageHolder holder = null;

       if(row == null)
       {
           LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
           row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

           holder = new ImageHolder();
           holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvDateVal);
           holder.txtDate = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvDateNum);
           holder.txtID = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvReasonVal);
           row.setTag(holder);
       }
       else
       {
           holder = (ImageHolder)row.getTag();
       }

       SetRows myImage = data.get(position);
       int inReason = myImage.name.indexOf(",");
       String strR = myImage.name.substring(0, inReason);
       Spannable WordToSpan = new SpannableString(strR);
       WordToSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#4787ED")), 0, WordToSpan.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
       String strRNext = myImage.name.substring(inReason, myImage.name.length());
       Spannable WordToSpan1 = new SpannableString(strRNext);
       WordToSpan1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(R.color.dateholiday), 0, WordToSpan1.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

       holder.txtTitle.setText(TextUtils.concat(WordToSpan, WordToSpan1));
       holder.txtID.setText(myImage.id);
       holder.txtDate.setText(myImage.date);
       if (myImage.name.contains(df.format(Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US).getTime()))) {
           Toast.makeText(getContext(), String.valueOf(myImage.name.contains(df.format(Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US).getTime()))), 2000).show();
           row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F0DEEDF3"));
       }
       return row;
   }

   static class ImageHolder
   {
       TextView txtTitle;
       TextView txtID;
       TextView txtDate;
   }
}
```

As you can see I am using the IF condition which should ONLY allow for one row to have the background color if met.

Image: http://i59.tinypic.com/2wmhtht.png

Image: http://i62.tinypic.com/9i7pjn.png

Comment: Show some code! And make sure you're using [ViewHolders](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html)

Comment: Posted the code to my adapter class along with the image

Comment: You also need to put in the else condition in the getView method. It should contain something on the following lines - `row.setBackgroundColor(<original-color-of-the-row-or-transparent-if-none)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Multiple changes occur because u probably do this in ur code. if(condition){// set bg}.

    // you need to do
    if(condition){// set bg}
    else
    {
    // set bg to default
    }

if (myImage.name.contains(df.format(Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US).getTime()))) {
           Toast.makeText(getContext(), String.valueOf(myImage.name.contains(df.format(Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US).getTime()))), 2000).show();
           row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F0DEEDF3"));
       }
else
{
row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ur original color hex code here"));
}
```

Comment: Added my custom adapter class and images for view

Comment: @user3326071 same wat i guessed u need to reset background

Comment: WOW... simple method but totally forgot about it. How can I set it to the default color?

Comment: @user3326071 depends on what is the original color defined in the layout xml just set to that

Comment: Sorry can't upvote AND accept so I just accepted it. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to change individual rows I would adjust color via the adapter class. Otherwise use the Activity / Fragment to change the entire background as needed.

Comment: I added my adapter class.